# VNC / Ubuntu 18.04 / xfce4: can't launch executables with a GUI

Tags: permissions, xfce, executable, vnc, vncviewer

I'm using VNC remote desktop to visually access a remote Ubuntu 18.04 machine with a xfce4 GUI. VNC works fine. SSH shell works fine. The 2 programs with a graphic UI I'd like to launch are nedit (a visual editor, compiled) and Unity (a game dev IDE). They both have the +x permissions, which I can see in the shell.

[image: Nedit permissions]
[image: Unity permissions]

In VNC, when I click "Properties", I don't see a "Run this as a program" option on either of them, just write/read.

[image: VNC permissions]

When I double click on an either "executable" in VNC's file manager, I get some odd message "Unable to set the xfce4 Display Settings" as if the "executables" were arguments for "Start with a Display".

[image]

When installing, I saw the Unity GUI in VNC briefly, so I know running Unity is technically possible.

The content of ~/.vnc/xstartup:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the system is raising a version mismatch error, not a permission issue.
To resolve that isue, you need to remove any X11 configuration file causing this mismatch conflict:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Or,

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf
```

Log out, log back in.

Because what's happening is that your xfce4 setting is conflicting with your default X11 setting.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see anything "xorg" in /etc/X11, only these: Xreset, Xresources, Xsession.d, XvMCConfig, rgb.txt, xkb, Xreset.d, Xsession, Xsession. options, Xwrapper.config, fonts, xinit, xsm, app-defaults

Comment: In this case try alter the path to X11 config file by issuing command like: #mkdir X11dir && mv /etc/X11/* ~/X11dir you will get those files as backup inside X11dir directory.